# Angular 1.6.9 @uiRouter: Error: [ng:cpws] Can't copy! Making copies of Window or Scope instances is not supported

Tags: angularjs, gulp, angular-ui-router

I am trying to use gulp-browsify to load all the dependencies in one `app-release.js` file.

The file builds fine but when I try to inject `@uiRouter` dependency I get the following error in the browser [image]

Where as if I inject `angular-route` it works fine.

Here is the code

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
var buffer = require('gulp-buffer');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.src('app.js')
        .pipe(browserify({
            insertGlobals: false,
            debug: true
        }))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(rename('app-release.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/'));
});
```

**app.js**

```
var angular = require('angular');
var uiRouter = require('@uirouter/angularjs');
var ngRoute = require('angular-route');

var app = angular.module("app",[uiRouter]);

app.config(function($stateProvider) {
    var helloState = {
        name: 'hello',
        url: '/',
        template: '<h3>hello world!</h3>'
    }

    var aboutState = {
        name: 'about',
        url: '/about',
        template: '<h3>Its the UI-Router hello world app!</h3>'
    }

    $stateProvider.state(helloState);
    $stateProvider.state(aboutState);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ui Router Test</title>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>-->
    <script src="app/app-release.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a ui-sref="hello">Hello</a>
<a ui-sref="about">About</a>
<p></p>
<!--<a href="#!red">Red</a>-->
<!--<a href="#!green">Green</a>-->
<!--<a href="#!blue">Blue</a>-->
<!--<div ng-view></div>-->
<ui-view></ui-view>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for providing help :)

Comment: In your index.html file I don't see where you are including the ui-router files? This is usually what causes these errors.

Comment: @Tyler I am using browsify by gulp. Which writes all the require dependencies specified in app.js into app-release.js

Comment: Any solutions for this issue? I have the same problem...

Comment: @w0ns88 try my answer :)

Answer (score 5):

i might be too late to help you, but maybe this will help someone else, the problem is the way in which the uiRouter module is defined, the way you have it set up your `uiRouter` variable holds an object, the UiRouter object, but it expects a string to be injected into your module declaration.

That string can be obtained from the default export and the way you get that is by declaring `var uiRouter = require('@uirouter/angularjs').default` as oposed to the way you're doing it above.

Once you declare `.default` at the end your variable will hold the **string** *"ui.router"* as opposed to the UI Router object and you may now pass that variable as you're doing.

*Note that you wouldn't have this problem if you were using ES6 style import statements as opposed to a commonJs require.*

**TLDR**

Add `.default` to the end of the uiRouter require call.